# Unable to add Customer Attribute in broadleaf

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf, broadleaf-commerce

I am using DemoSite-broadleaf-5.2.4-GA and following below tutorial

https://www.broadleafcommerce.com/docs/core/current/tutorials/getting-started-tutorials/adding-customer-attribute-tutorial

but I am getting

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring4.processor.SpringInputGeneralFieldTagProcessor' (template: "authentication/registerForm" - line 71, col 24)
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.java:117) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractElementTagProcessor.process(AbstractElementTagProcessor.java:95) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.util.ProcessorConfigurationUtils$ElementTagProcessorWrapper.process(ProcessorConfigurationUtils.java:633) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.ProcessorTemplateHandler.handleStandaloneElement(ProcessorTemplateHandler.java:918) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.StandaloneElementTag.beHandled(StandaloneElementTag.java:228) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.Model.process(Model.java:282) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.ProcessorTemplateHandler.handleOpenElement(ProcessorTemplateHandler.java:1587) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.OpenElementTag.beHandled(OpenElementTag.java:205) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.Model.process(Model.java:282) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.Model.process(Model.java:290) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.GatheringModelProcessable.process(GatheringModelProcessable.java:78) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.ProcessorTemplateHandler.handleCloseElement(ProcessorTemplateHandler.java:1640) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.CloseElementTag.beHandled(CloseElementTag.java:139) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.Model.process(Model.java:282) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.ProcessorTemplateHandler.handleOpenElement(ProcessorTemplateHandler.java:1587) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.OpenElementTag.beHandled(OpenElementTag.java:205) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.Model.process(Model.java:282) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.ProcessorTemplateHandler.handleOpenElement(ProcessorTemplateHandler.java:1587

...............................

**Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'referralCode' of bean class [org.broadleafcommerce.profile.web.core.form.RegisterCustomerForm]: Bean property 'referralCode' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?**
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.getPropertyValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:631) ~[spring-beans-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.getPropertyValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:622) ~[spring-beans-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.validation.AbstractPropertyBindingResult.getActualFieldValue(AbstractPropertyBindingResult.java:99) ~[spring-context-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.validation.AbstractBindingResult.getFieldValue(AbstractBindingResult.java:229) ~[spring-context-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:118) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
```

Answer (score 1):

Posting your `registerForm.html` and your extension of `RegisterCustomerForm.java` would help. From the stack trace, it seems like there is a Thymeleaf expression that is attempting to access `RegisterCustomerForm.referralCode`. This field is not out-of-box, so you would have had to extend RegisterCustomerForm to add that field. Make sure the controller that is serving the registration page is using your extension of RegisterCustomerForm.